# Less gets keyboard input from stderr?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-coreutils

I'm taking a look at the code to the 'less' utility, specifically how it gets keyboard input. Interestingly, on line 80 of ttyin.c, it sets the file descriptor to read from:

```
     /*
      * Try /dev/tty.
      * If that doesn't work, use file descriptor 2,
      * which in Unix is usually attached to the screen,
      * but also usually lets you read from the keyboard.
      */
  #if OS2
      /* The __open() system call translates "/dev/tty" to "con". */
      tty = __open("/dev/tty", OPEN_READ);
  #else
      tty = open("/dev/tty", OPEN_READ);
  #endif
      if (tty < 0)
          tty = 2;
```

Isn't file descriptor 2 stderr? If so, WTH?! I thought keyboard input was sent through stdin.

Interestingly, even if you do `ls -l * | less`, after the file finishes loading, you can still use the keyboard to scroll up and down, but if you do `ls -l * | vi`, then vi will yell at you because it doesn't read from stdin. What's the big idea? How did I end up in this strange new land where stderr is both a way to report errors to the screen and read from the keyboard? I don't think I'm in Kansas anymore...

Comment: BTW, if you write `ls -l * | vim -`, vim will perform similar magic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ ls -l /dev/fd/
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 2009-09-17 16:52 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 2009-09-17 16:52 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 me me 64 2009-09-17 16:52 2 -> /dev/pts/4
```

When logged in at an interative terminal, all three standard file descriptors point to the same thing: your TTY (or pseudo-TTY).

```
$ ls -fl /dev/std{in,out,err}
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-09-13 01:57 /dev/stdin -> fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-09-13 01:57 /dev/stdout -> fd/1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2009-09-13 01:57 /dev/stderr -> fd/2
```

By convention, we read from `0` and write to `1` and `2`.  However, nothing prevents us from doing otherwise.

When your shell runs `ls -l * | less`, it creates a pipe from `ls`'s file descriptor `1` to `less`'s file descriptor `0`.  Obviously, `less` can no longer read the user's keyboard input from file descriptor `0` – it tries to get the TTY back however it can.

If `less` has not been detached from the terminal, `open("/dev/tty")` will give it the TTY.

However, in case that fails... what can you do?  `less` makes one last attempt at getting the TTY, assuming that file descriptor `2` is attached to the same thing that file descriptor `0` would be attached to, if it weren't redirected.

This **is not** failproof:

```
$ ls -l * | setsid less 2>/dev/null
```

Here, `less` is given its own session (so it is no longer a part of the terminal's active process group, causing `open("/dev/tty")` to fail), and its file descriptor `2` has been changed – now `less` exits immediately, because it is outputting to a TTY yet it fails to get any user input.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Because stderr is nothing more than juts a file descriptor that's actually connected to the terminal, it can read or write from it as it pleases. THAT'S COOL! Thank you, ephemient.

Comment: Wouldn't file descriptor `2` only be open for writing, though?

Comment: @BlacklightShining Your terminal emulator probably started your shell using something like [`forkpty`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminal-Pairs.html), which creates a single read-write file descriptor to the pseudo-TTY and dup's it to 0,1,2.

Comment: what I don't understand is that if it reads from /dev/tty isn't getting a bunch of data from stdin (the producer in the pipeline)? so I guess it's looking for certain special keystrokes like / ?

Answer (score 3):

Well... first off, you seem to missing the `open()` call which opens '/dev/tty'. It only uses file descriptor 2 if the call to open() fails. On a standard Linux system, and probably many Unices, '/dev/tty' exists and is unlikely to cause a fail.

Secondly, the comment at the top provides a limited amount of explanation as to why they fall back to file descriptor 2. My guess is that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are pretty much connected to '/dev/tty/' anyway, unless redirected. And since the most common redirections for for stdin and/ or stdout (via piping or `<` / `>`), but less often for `stderr`, odds on are that using `stderr` would be most likely to still be connect to the "keyboard".

Comment: The reason for using stderr is that stdin/stdout are more likely to be pipes created by the spawning shell.   Piping into or out of less is a noop, but does work.  But redirecting stderr of a less command specifically has little value and isn't likely to be done.  So betting that stderr is "really" the terminal device is a reasonable guess.

Answer (score 2):

The same question with an answer ultimately from the person who asked it is on [linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/more-and-less-piped-commands-the-mystery-of-the-hidden-stdin-729318/) although they quote slightly different source from `less`. And no, I don't understand most of it so I can't help beyond that :)

Answer (score -2):

It appears to be Linux specific functionality that sends keyboard input to FD 2.

Comment: Blatantly false.  Try this on any other UNIX.