# How does "mysql" ask for a password?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, stdin

If I run the command-line program mysql like

```
 mysql -u someone -p < sql-file
```

so that a password is required (`-p`), it prompts for a password:

```
 Enter password:
```

However, as you can see from the above, standard input is actually a file, `sql-file`.

How does "mysql" (or similar programs) do this?

(Please note that this is not a question about MySQL in particular, I am interested in how a C program can access the terminal like this.)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627138/retrieving-stdin-after-using-the-redirection-operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open `/dev/tty` as a file in read-mode, and then read from it.

Comment: It is worth adding that even if standard input has been redirected, the process still has a controlling terminal (if it was run from a shell as described).  `/dev/tty` refers to this controlling terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are usually read directly from the terminal. In fact, there's a function [`getpass`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/getpass.html) that does just this.

Answer (score 0):

When you pipe in a file, it comes on stdin. Applications that read passwords usually open up a separate input stream.

The best way to accomplish your goal is to use [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn mysql
expect "*password*"
send "your_password_here"
```