# Shell Pipe Process Group: ls | cat works but ls | more hangs?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm implementing my own tiny shell. Both `ls | cat` and `ls | more` work well if I don't create a new group for these two child processes.

However, after I create a new process group for these two processes (the first one `ls` process is the leader process) by simply calling `setpgid` in the parent process. `ls | cat` always works but `ls | more` hangs.

It looks like one of my process is getting stuck at the `dup2` system call. Is there any other things I need to consider? What happens if `ls` terminates first before I call `setpgid` for `more` process? Do I need to block `ls` process not to call `execve` until `setpgid` is done for `more` process?

---

EDIT:

My code:
Sometimes it gets stuck. But when I tried to add `printf` to locate the position, it's finished successfully. No error arises.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      perror(msg);                                  \
      exit(1);                                      \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

#define SAFE_CLOSE_NOT_STD(fd) do {                                 \
    if (fd != STDIN_FILENO && fd != STDOUT_FILENO && fd != -1) {    \
      CHECK(close(fd), "close error");                              \
      fd = -1;                                                      \
    }                                                               \
  } while(0)

int main () {
  int ls_pid, more_pid;
  int pipefd[2];
  char *ls_argv[] = { "/bin/ls", NULL };
  char *more_argv[] = { "/usr/bin/more", NULL };

  CHECK(pipe(pipefd), "pipe error");

  CHECK(ls_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!ls_pid) {
    CHECK(dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO), "dup2 error");
    CHECK(close(pipefd[1]), "close error");
    CHECK(execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv), "execvp error");
  } else {
    SAFE_CLOSE_NOT_STD(pipefd[1]);
  }
  setpgid(ls_pid, ls_pid);

  CHECK(more_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!more_pid) {
    CHECK(dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO), "dup2 error");
    CHECK(close(pipefd[0]), "close error");
    CHECK(execvp(more_argv[0], more_argv), "execvp error");
  } else {
    SAFE_CLOSE_NOT_STD(pipefd[0]);
  }

  setpgid(more_pid, ls_pid); // it works if I remove this line

  CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");
  CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");

  printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Comment: You should probably add some of your code that is being executed around the hang.

Comment: Can I use `setpgid` in the parent process while the child process is in `execve`?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] so others can help debug?

Comment: You should [call `setpgid`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html) in the parent _and_ the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `_exit()`, not `exit()`, after `fork()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5423108). (That's not the real problem here, but you should fix it.)

What happens here is that `more` is not in the current foreground process group, so it is not allowed to read input from the terminal and gets `SIGTTIN` instead. [Use `tcsetpgrp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Foreground-and-Background.html).

Comment: Do you mean the `more` process becomes background process after the pgid of the `ls` process is changed? But if I change `/usr/bin/more` to `/bin/cat`, it works well and never hangs. Why?

Comment: @K.Miao `more` is initially in the same process group as your program, which is foreground. As soon as you put it into the new process group, it is in the background. `cat` doesn't read from the terminal so it doesn't get `SIGTTIN`. Depending on terminal configuration, it could potentially get `SIGTTOU`, but all shells turn that off by default. `stty tostop` to demonstrate.

Comment: I've overwritten the stdin to the pipe read end for the `more` process. It reads from the pipe but not stdin. Does it still get `SIGTTIN`? I just tried to register handler for `SIGTTIN` and `SIGTTOU` in the parent process before calling any `fork()`. The program hangs but I didn't see any `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU`.

Comment: @K.Miao `more` reads user input from the terminal even when stdin is not the terminal (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441368 for how `less` works). The parent process doesn't get `SIGTTIN`, only the process trying to read from stdin while in the background.

Comment: Since I register the handlers in the parent process, wouldn't it be inherited to both child processes? Is there any other ways to verify the answer? THANKS!!

Comment: @K.Miao Even if you ignore `SIGTTIN`, it doesn't change the fact that `read` returns nothing and `more` refuses to work. Actually, tracing the whole thing with `strace -f` it appears that `more` putting the terminal into raw mode causes it to receive a `SIGTTOU` before writing anything else. Still, the underlying cause is the same: not the terminal's foreground process group.

Comment: I register a `SIGTTOU` and a `SIGTTIN` handler for the `more` process. In the handler I simply call `_exit(1)`. But it still gets stuck. Shouldn't it terminate instead of stuck?

Comment: @K.Miao That handler can't be inherited across `exec` - the functions live in a specific address space, which gets wiped out. Only default and ignore signal handlers can be inherited.

Comment: So I need to guarantee `tcsetpgrp` is executed before `execve` is executed in the `more` process, right? How do I achieve this? Do I need to use shared memory to keep the `more` process waiting until `tcsetpgrp` is executed? Any elegant ways to deal with this?